# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException A network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: c#, sql, database

As the title suggests this is the exception from my stacktrace.

I am trying to obtain a connection to my SQL Server 2008 R2 database hosted on a windows 2003 server.

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=server\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sqlDB;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: SOLVED: Was SQL BROWser service not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

The [Resolving “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…”](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/) article explains how to address this issue.  I hope, it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may help you to create your database

Open command prompt, then type services.msc
Now Services window will be opened

And, Open SQL Server Browser,Enable this and start it

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing database in SQL Server Object Explorer helped me with that issue.