# cannot connect sql server 2008 from another computer

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, connection-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException A network-related or instance-specific error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627159/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

i have winform application in c# which connect to my own db and its working fine my current sql connection string is :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ITPL_PC1;Initial Catalog=Data_Project;Persist Security Info=True;user id=sa;Password=insforia");
```

but when i am taking this winform to another computer its not working .. then i am changing my connection string to :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.28\\ITPL_PC1;Initial Catalog=Data_Project;Persist Security Info=True;user id=sa;Password=insforia");
```

but its not working ...

i have changed all the settings in sql server of remote access but still it showing an error

```
Sql Exception was unhandled 
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection      to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

is my connection string is wrong? what it should be?

pls help me out

Comment: yes i made the changes in firewall settings

Comment: Have you enabled the TCP-IP Client Protocol using Sql Server Configuration Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Data Source=ITPL_PC1
```

Identifies a *server* called `ITPL_PC1`. You're connecting to the default instance on this server.

```
Data Source=192.168.0.28\ITPL_PC1
```

Identifies an *instance* called `ITPL_PC1` running on a server with IP address 192.168.0.28. We don't know the name of this server.

If the instance you want to connect to is the default instance on `ITPL_PC1`, then the first version should always work (provided `ITPL_PC1` can be resolved).

Comment: thanks thank you allot .... it just worked ... actually `Data Source=192.168.0.28\ITPL_PC1` i found this by googling so i used it but thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Windows security might be preventing the access. You can try the below.
1.Go to the service management console of windows by typing `services.msc` in the run window.
2. In the window displayed you can see a list of services. From the list find out `Base Filtering Engine`.  
3.Right click and stop it. Its done

I have fixed the same issue like this after lot of googling.(For me it was not working even after enabling TCP/IP from sql configuration manager)

Answer (score 0):

```
           First you open SQL managnebt studio and connect to another pc sql server :

         Please follow bolew step :
            Strat -> program -> window sql server 2008 -> configuration tools 
            --> sql server Configuration manager -->
            Start sql server browser service
    -----------
    Next --->Sql serverNetework COnfiguration  --> Enable all Protocls and
    also Sql Native Client.. --> Enable all Protocls  then
    --------------
    reatsrt all service and connect to sql
-------------------------------------------------
If you get connection then SQL Database to connect database from visual studio from there to find connection string and copy and paste to connection string.
```